# Extract Number from Number plate - deblurring techniques

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, numbers

I have an image of a number plate and my task is to find the number/text from that plate. How I can solve this?

[image: blurry number plate]

Are there any popular algorithms to deblurr the image and get the text from the image?

Answer (score 0):

1. It's a motion blur, you can use simple debluring from OpenCV: https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d1/dfd/tutorial_motion_deblur_filter.html
2. The more complicated way - [DeblurNet](https://github.com/KupynOrest/DeblurGAN)